# Is a string necessarily smaller than a Vector3 in storage?

Tags: lua, game-engine, lua-api, coregames

I'm working on a system in Core to save the transforms of furniture, specifically position and rotation, which are both Vector3's. I have these in player storage, so at some point to save all the player's furniture, I think I will end up maxing out player storage. So I'm converting all the Vector3's to strings, with a modified version of a Roblox script that I found:

```
local API = {}

API.VectorToString = function(vec)
    return math.floor(vec.x*100)/100 ..' '.. math.floor(vec.y*100)/100 ..' '.. math.floor(vec.z*100)/100
end

API.StringToVector = function(str)
    local tab = {}
    for a in string.gmatch(str,"(%-?%d*%.?%d+)") do
        table.insert(tab,a)
    end
    return Vector3.New(tab[1],tab[2],tab[3])
end

return API
```

So the question is, does converting all these Vectors to strings actually save space in my player data storage?

Comment: that would depend on how many digits you have. the Vector3 will always consume the same memory no matter the values. a strings memory size depends the number of digits you represent with it. why don't you just give it a try and compare it yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the Vector3 format is more efficient than a string conversion for storage. Each number in the Vector3 requires 4 bytes to be stored because each number is a 16-bit float. By converting the Vector3 values to strings, additional bytes are required (each digit you add requires one byte since a character requires one byte). If you need to store a Vector3 as a string I would suggest using the method below.

For anyone who would like to learn how computers can store such a wide range of numbers in only four bytes, I would highly recommend researching the IEEE 754 format.

[Video that explains the IEEE754 Format](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RuKkePyo9zk&t=521s&ab_channel=ComputerScience)

You can use the **string.pack** and **string.unpack** functions to convert floats to byte arrays which can be sent as strings. This method will only require 12 bytes (12 characters) in total when sending data and has around 5 to 6 decimals points of precision. While this method may only save a few bytes it will allow you to send/save far more precise numbers/positions.

```lua
local API = {}

API.VectorToString = function(vec) 
    --Convert the x,y,z positions to bytes 
    local byteXValue = string.pack('f', vec.x, 0) 
    local byteYValue = string.pack('f', vec.y, 0) 
    local byteZValue = string.pack('f', vec.z, 0) 
    --Combine the floats bytes into one string
    local combinedBytes = byteXValue + byteYValue + byteZValue
    return combinedBytes 
end

API.StringToVector = function(str) 
    --Convert the x,y,z positions from bytes to float values
    --Every 4th byte represents a new float value
    local byteXValue = string.unpack('f', string.sub(1, 4)) 
    local byteYValue = string.unpack('f', string.sub(5, 8)) 
    local byteZValue = string.unpack('f', string.sub(9, 12)) 
    --Combine the x,y,z values into one Vector3 object
    return Vector3.New(byteXValue, byteYValue, byteZValue) 
end

return API
```

[String pack function documentation](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-string.pack)

Answer (score 1):

It can be written a little shorter and with fewer memory allocations

```lua
    local v3 = Vector3.New(111, 222, 333)
    local v3str = string.pack("fff", v3.x, v3.y, v3.z)
    local x, y, z = string.unpack("fff", v3str)
    local v31 = Vector3.New(x, y, z)
    assert(v3 == v31)
```

But you need to remember that most Core API functions do not tolerate zero-bytes in strings, and if you want to store those strings in Storage or use them as an event argument - you should text-encode them (Base64 is a common option).